# I am having issues getting a return from my function

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a program to compare ways of sorting.  I am using the comparisons made to track the efficiency of each program.  I have been able to track how many comparisons are made, but i cannot get the comparisons from the function back into the original variable.

```
import random

# allows user to create a set of numbers, at their desiered length
setSize = int(input('How many numbers are we sorting today?'))
# creates a random list of numbers between 0 and 999,999
numbers = random.sample(range(0, 999999), setSize)

SelectionCount = 0

def sort (arr, a, b, i, j, count):
    while j < a:
        while i < a:
            if arr[b] > arr[i]:
                b = i
                count += 1
            i += 1

        arr[j], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[j]
        j += 1
        i = j
        b = i

sort(numbers, setSize, 0, 0, 0, SelectionCount)

print("The sort has been completed, there were " + str(SelectionCount) + " comparisons made!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the count from the function. Also, you don't have to put `a, b, i, j` as function parameters, just initialize them inside the function.

For example:

```
import random

# allows user to create a set of numbers, at their desiered length
setSize = int(input('How many numbers are we sorting today?'))
# creates a random list of numbers between 0 and 999,999
numbers = random.sample(range(0, 999999), setSize)

def sort (arr):
    a, b = len(arr), 0
    i, j = 0, 0
    count = 0

    while j < a:
        while i < a:
            if arr[b] > arr[i]:
                b = i
                count += 1
            i += 1

        arr[j], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[j]
        j += 1
        i = j
        b = i
    return count

SelectionCount = sort(numbers)

print("The sort has been completed, there were " + str(SelectionCount) + " comparisons made!")
```

Prints:

```
How many numbers are we sorting today?10
The sort has been completed, there were 12 comparisons made!
```

Comment: Okay, that worked.  I tried using return earlier but I had no idea how it worked, so it didn't do what I needed.  Thank you!